# How do I keep data in a cell static as new data is entered into the worksheet from another worksheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, static

I have 2 worksheets, `Master` & `Working`. The Master sheet contains the master data (columns A-Z), and the Working sheet contains the working data (columns A-AL).

I have sorted the data in the Master sheet alphabetically to allow for folks to find their items quickly.

Whenever someone puts an `'x'` into `column A` of `Master`, then it copies columns `B-Z` into `columns M-AL` of the `Working` sheet.

The remaining columns in the Working sheet (cols `A-L`) are for manual data entry.

It seems that the data being copied into the Working sheet is also alphabetized - which is fine. However, whenever manual data is entered into the Working sheet, it does not stay within the proper row for the (Master) data that it is related to.

I constantly need to move the manual data down or up depending upon how many lines were automatically created when the Master data was pulled into the sheet. `How do I keep the manual data static where it relates to the Master data for that row?`

This is the formula that I am using to pull the Master data into the Working sheet

```
=QUERY('FY22 Q2'!A3:Z3886, "SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z WHERE A = 'x'", -1)
```

Please help. I am still a newbie with all of this spreadsheet stuff so please try to speak in layman's terms as much as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Help will come sooner if you provide access to the problem spreadsheet, as well as show unwanted behavior and desirable (screenshots).

Comment: try to add `sort()` to the query. ref : https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sort-function

Comment: Hi there, are you using Google Sheets or Microsoft Excel? In addition, please consider adding helpful information as @BorisBaublys suggested. Check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have recreated the Google Sheet with some dummy data. Here is the link - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/163YsJCN28T27-UiU80eqXiOfCpYfH1Gm3TCt-Wnam_o/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: The Master sheet has 2 types of data, Original & New. The New data is added as more projects arise for this quarter end. Whenever New data is added, and an "x" is marked within column A of the Master, it gets pulled into the Working Sheet and placed at the bottom of the sheet. Whenever Original data is marked with an "x", it is added alphabetically to the Working sheet, rather than at the bottom (e.g. next empty row). I think this is the issue. I want any Master data marked with an "x" to appear on the next row of the Working sheet, and NOT alphabetically.

Comment: I added a sort to the query, as suggested by p._phidot....it did not work. Any original data pulled in from the Master sheet still causes the new line to shift, all but the manual, data. I need all manual data in the Working sheet to stay with it's corresponding data pulled from the Master sheet.

Comment: Have the issue been fixed? I am trying to reproduce it but I get the new data at the bottom rather than ordered alphabetically. Maybe I am misunderstanding something. I have copied an Original row without the `x` in the last position of `MasterData`, I have marked the x and the data has appeared at the bottom in `WorkingData`. Could you attach a picture or video of the actual behavior?

Comment: No it hasn't. But since you ate getting the result that I want, then it leads me to believe that there may be an issue with the source data that I'm pulling from to create my Master. At this point, however, finding a solution is moot because the EOQ is Friday and I have just been adjusting the data manually, as needed. Thank you for your help.